# Understanding : $\int \frac{1}{x^{-1}+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, fractions

I am trying to practice integrating the following:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^{-1}+1}dx$$

The first step of simplifying the fraction does not make sense to me in how it becomes: $$-\frac{1}{1+x}+1 $$

Could someone please explain how this step is done?

Comment: Hint. "It" is your *integrand*.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{1}{x^{-1}+1} = \frac{x}{1+x} \\
= \frac{1+x-1}{1+x}\\
= 1-\frac{1}{1+x}\\
= -\frac{1}{1+x}+1\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note:

$$\frac{1}{x^{-1} + 1}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + 1}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\frac{1 + x}{x}}$$
$$ = \frac{x}{1 + x}$$
$$ = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Combining the other two answers, we can solve the integral:

\begin{align}
&\quad\int\frac{1}{x^{-1}+1}\ dx\\
&=\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+1}\ dx\\
&=\int\frac{1}{\frac{x+1}{x}}\ dx\\
&=\int\frac{x}{x+1}\ dx
\end{align}

Now, by $u$-sub, we can apply the substitution $u=x+1$.

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=1\\
du&=dx
\end{align}

We now get

\begin{align}
&\quad\int\frac{x}{x+1}\ dx\\
&=\int\frac{u-1}{u}\ du\\
&=\int1-u^{-1}\ du\\
&=u-\ln|u|+c\\
&=(x+1)-\ln|x+1|+c
\end{align}